Nginx basic auth fails with Unauthorizaed even on correct credentials
I have an nginx proxy redirect working inside the docker container to redirect all the requests to the correct service. I have a problem with basic_auth since it does not work as expected. Below is a config for the main server proxy location to point to maildev container.
            location /backend_api_v2/swagger.json {
                   auth_basic               "Restricted";
                   auth_basic_user_file     /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.htpasswd;

                   proxy_pass               http://${BACKEND_HOST_PORT}/backendAPI/swagger.json;
                   proxy_redirect           default;
            }

If the authorization is removed this request does go through and show the swagger definition correctly. What else is interesting is that it is not the nginx that returns 401 but the undertow realm security which even weirder since that endpoint doesn't require auth.
Here is the headers that get returned.
Any help will be appreciated 07

It seems like passing populate Authorization header to the api container made it try to use the credentials with Undertow which would not be valid (even though it is an open endpoint).
I have solved by setting the Authorization header to nothing which makes it work. Below is the modified config to make it work.
            location /backend_api_v2/swagger.json {
               auth_basic               "Restricted";
               auth_basic_user_file     /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.htpasswd;
               proxy_set_header         Authorization "";
               proxy_pass               http://${BACKEND_HOST_PORT}/backendAPI/swagger.json;
        }

